# App connected to MongoDB database but database not visible with "show dbs" prompt in command line

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have successfully connected my database called "Cats" using MongoDB, however, when I type "show dbs" in the command line I'm not able to see it. Do you know what step(s) I have missed and how I'm able to interact with this database from the command line?

This is all I see:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

Comment: if the answer helps you, please click on tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of problem

Comment: Thanks Varman, that's helpful. The problem I'm still having is that my existing db and collections on MongoDB Atlas don't appear in the command line in AWS. It may be because my data path is incorrect but I'm not sure how to rectify it. I have upvoted you but my reputation less than 15.

Comment: In mongo atlas it will give u the connection string. Just copy and paste in the mongo.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create db

```
use Cats
```

To check current database that you selected

```
db
```

`show dbs` doeosn't show until you **insert at least one document** into your `Cats` to display database.

```
db.animal.insert({"name":"dogs"})
```

Then type

```
show dbs
```